# Converting objects to JSON in VBA

Tags: json, vba, ms-office

I know it's possible to use a library like VBAJSON to convert an array or a dictionary to json, but not a custom class instance in office 2013.

Searching turns up no libraries for handling objects to json, so I figure there must be some other way.

So, I'm wondering:

- is it possible for an object to be recursively converted to a dictionary so the to-json conversion can then happen, without having to write a lengthy custom "ToDictionary" method for each class?
- is there another way (other than not using objects) that json output can be reached from custom class objects?

  At the moment, I've written ToDictionary methods for each class to output the instance as a dictionary. It's messy, but gets the job done.

Comment: I came across [this](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/classserialization) recently but have not gone further than cursory review. At a glance, though, it looks like it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I saw it too, from what I could see, it uses a custom "object" `CObject` or such that is essentially a dictionary which is fed to the json conversion function

Comment: Hmmm ok I looked a little closer (but still not close enough) my first impression was that it was a generic Stringify function, but now I think maybe it's specific only to the one particular Class.

Comment: One idea,  not always ideal, would be to use JSON or XML representation of your data *instead* of VBA class object.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where that's ever ideal. Objects are far more flexible than json data

Comment: I suppose it depends on the application and use-cases. I maintain a large PPT app that communicates via Com server (python app).  We have VBA classes but pass data as variant array thru Com, where python convert to a dictionary and then xml. In hinds8ght, we have some redundancy which makes the code less flexible and harder to maintain than if we had just started with XML schema.  But in my example, the python client does all of the heavy lifting anyways...

Answer (score 15):

It's an old question, but without an answer, so let me try to answer with code.

I built a function to convert VBA structure (using Dictionary) to JSON. This function accepts nested object (nested Dictionary):

```
Function ToJson(ByVal dict As Object) As String
    Dim key As Variant, result As String, value As String

    result = "{"
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        result = result & IIf(Len(result) > 1, ",", "")

        If TypeName(dict(key)) = "Dictionary" Then
            value = ToJson(dict(key))
            ToJson = value
        Else
            value = """" & dict(key) & """"
        End If

        result = result & """" & key & """:" & value & ""
    Next key
    result = result & "}"

    ToJson = result
End Function
```

Test:

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim body As String
    Set dictSubValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictBody = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dictSubValues.Add "SubValue1", "2.1"
    dictSubValues.Add "SubValue2", "2.2"

    dictBody.Add "Value1", "1"
    dictBody.Add "Value2", dictSubValues

    body = ToJson(dictBody)
    Debug.Print (body)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
{
   "Value1":"1",
   "Value2":{
      "SubValue1":"2.1",
      "SubValue2":"2.2"
   }
}
```

Comment: For handling double quotes in the value, a simple Replace is enough.
`value = """" & Replace(dict(key), """", "\""") & """"`
For a complete solution, replace also `vbBack->\b; vbCr->\r; vbLf->\n; vbTab->\t; \->\\`

Answer (score 1):

When I first started to write this question I was positvely stuck. Then I had a lightbulb moment to write a ToDictionary method for the class to convert the object to a dictionary how I want it.

So something like:

```
public function ToDictionary() as string
    dim d as dictionary
    set d = new dictionary
    d.add "id" Me!id
    d.add "title" Me!title
    ...
    Set ToDictionary = d
    set d = Nothing
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the object to XML and from there it would be easier to convert to JSON and there are many posts online on how to do it.

Note however that converting XML to JSON isn't as trivial as it sounds and there are many pitfalls that you should be aware of.