# Convert Whatsapp API CURL Command line to VBA

Tags: vba, curl, xmlhttprequest, whatsapp

Just for fun, and maybe for future use, I'm trying to run a VBA code where it sends a WhatsApp message whenever something happens.

Right now I'm having trouble on converting the API CURL command that WhatsApp provides:

```
curl -X  POST \
'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '
    {
      "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
      "recipient_type": "individual",
      "to": "PHONE_NUMBER",
      "type": "text",
      "text": { // the text object
        "preview_url": false,
        "body": "MESSAGE_CONTENT"
        }
    }'
```

Using some code examples on how to send SMS messages, I got to this point:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim INSTANCE_ID, URL As String
    Dim REQUEST As Object
    
    INSTANCE_ID = "EAA..."
    URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/196.../messages"
    
    Set REQUEST = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    With REQUEST
        .Open "POST", URL
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & INSTANCE_ID
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send "messaging_product=whatsapp&recipient_type=individual&to=5511...&type=text&text:{body:TEST}"
    End With
    
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Debug.Print "Status: " & REQUEST.Status & " - Text: " & REQUEST.responseText
    Set REQUEST = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Executing the code above, the response is:**

> Status: 400 - Text: {"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_data":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","details":"Parameter 'text' is mandatory for type 'text'"},"fbtrace_id":"AWr..."}}

It's my first time trying to execute an API via VBA.
I know that running this on Java would be much easier, but I think that this challenge would improve my understanding on the topic.

Comment: Is the text {body:TEST} valid JSON?  I think it'll need to be {"body":"TEST"}  but because you are in a VBA string you will have to double your quotes so {""body"":""test""}

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

After realising that the error was being caused by the terrible JSON i made (Thanks to [S Meaden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3607273/s-meaden)), i have found a really good post here on StackOverflow, showing how to create a propper JSON.

The solution: [Objects to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49018844/19908265)

The working code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim INSTANCE_ID, URL As String
Dim REQUEST As Object
Dim body As String
Set dictSubValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictBody = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

INSTANCE_ID = "EAA..."
URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/196.../messages"

Set REQUEST = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

dictSubValues.Add "preview_url", "false"
dictSubValues.Add "body", "TEST"

dictBody.Add "messaging_product", "whatsapp"
dictBody.Add "recipient_type", "individual"
dictBody.Add "to", "5511..."
dictBody.Add "type", "text"
dictBody.Add "text", dictSubValues

body = ToJson(dictBody)

With REQUEST
    .Open "POST", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & INSTANCE_ID
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send body
End With

Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Debug.Print "Status: " & REQUEST.Status & " - Text: " & REQUEST.responseText
Set REQUEST = Nothing
End Sub
```

The response:

> Status: 200 - Text: {"messaging_product":"whatsapp","contacts":[{"input":"5511...","wa_id":"5511..."}],"messages":[{"id":"wamid.HBg..."}]}

Answer (score 0):

Hi there It may my solution help you .. Just find the below solution for sending the custom template
Because we are getting same problem

Steps:-

1:- check your template .is you are passing the all param as your template need like you if you area passing header image etc.

2- add the type param in body
Like  :-  "type": "template"(don't miss it).

3 :- check my json

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "911234567890",
    "type": "template",//don't miss it
    "template": {
        "name": "website",
        "language": {
            "code": "en"
        },
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "body",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "Ritik"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "Rawat"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "748869282"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```